# Gitserver on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, gitlab, rails-api

I have a rails app which is meant to provide githosting. Each user can have multiple repositories. I have my web framework ready(creating issues, comments and creation of new repository, browser upload of file, edits etc). I have used rugged for git related works.

Now I want to allow user to be able to push/pull their repository from command line (`git push/pull path_to_repo`).
How do I communicate with my rails app through a command like `git push/pull`? I tried to go through [gitlab](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq) but their repo is just way too huge. I would be really grateful if someone can point me the right direction. gitlab seems to use [gitlab-shell](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell) but all of the code in gitlab-shell seems to be about authentication of user. When do they even perform the actual update of repo and how is it communicating with the actual repo?

Right now if I do something like:

```
git clone localhost:3000/data/repos/addie/fancy_project/satellite/.git/
```

I get following error:

> Cloning into 'satellite'... fatal: repository
>   'http://localhost:3000/data/repos/addie/fancy_project/satellite/.git/'
>   not found

and logger shows:

```
Started GET "/data/repos/addie/fancy_project/satellite/.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-06 01:30:03 +0530

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/data/repos/addie/fancy_project/satellite/.git/info/refs")
```

I know that a repo named .git exists at `public/data/repos/addie/fancy_project/satellite/`. It is rails router which is getting in way. Normal command over file system:

```
git clone my_project/public/data/repos/addie/fancy_project/satellite/.git
```

works just fine. I have enables post-update hook like it explains it [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#idp6187184)

Comment: Git talks to git repos.

Comment: yeah but how? I don't suppose if I provide just do `git push path_to_repo` and it will work? I also need to have an authentication layer in between and for that I need to involve my rails app.

Comment: @DaveNewton can you please check edit?

Comment: No idea what is wrong with your application. But there's Gitlab, which does the same job of hosting a git repo. Maybe you'll find it useful.

Comment: @DaveNewton what do you mean by "talks"?

Comment: @NickVolynkin "Operates on"/"interacts with"?

Comment: @NickVolynkin post-update hook creates `info/refs` files but since it gets caught in router it never gets executed and hence no `info/refs` file exits. Now I just need to find a way to execute `git update-server-info` in right directory when a pull request is made.